# Why can't Swift initializers call convenience initializers on their superclass?

Tags: class, initialization, swift

Consider the two classes:

```
class A {
    var x: Int

    init(x: Int) {
        self.x = x
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(x: 0)
    }
}

class B: A {
    init() {
        super.init() // Error: Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'A'
    }
}
```

I don't see why this isn't allowed. Ultimately, each class's designated initializer is called with any values they need, so why do I need to repeat myself in `B`'s `init` by specifying a default value for `x` again, when the convenience `init` in `A` will do just fine?

Comment: I searched for an answer but I can't find any that would satisfy me. It's probably some implementation reason. Maybe searching for designated initializers in another class is much easier than searching for convenience initializers... or something like that.

Comment: @Robert, thanks for your comments below. I think you could add them to your question, or even post an answer with what you received: "This is by design and any relevant bugs have been sorted out in this area.". So it looks they can't or don't want to explain the reason.

Answer (score 29):

This is Rule 1 of the "Initializer Chaining" rules as specified in the Swift Programming Guide, which reads:

> Rule 1: **Designated** initializers must call a **designated** initializer from their
>   immediate superclass.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

Emphasis mine. Designated initializers cannot call convenience initializers.

There is a diagram that goes along with the rules to demonstrate what initializer "directions" are allowed:

[image: Initializer Chaining]

Comment: But why is it done this way? The documentation just says that it simplifies the design, but I don't see how this is the case if I have to keep repeating myself by continually specifying default values on designated initializers I mostly don't care about when the default ones in the convenience initializers will do?

Comment: See @Sulthan's answer. I was incorrect in stating that a designated initializer could call a convenience initializer in its own class - in fact, a designated initializer cannot call a convenience initializer at all. (Answer updated.)

Comment: @Robert With regards to *why*, I still don't know. Maybe worth asking DTS or filing a radar?

Comment: I filed a bug 17266917 a couple days after this question, asking to be able to call convenience initialisers. No response yet, but I've not had any for any of my other Swift bug reports either!

Comment: Hopefully they will allow to call convenience initialisers. For some classes in the SDK there is no other way to achieve a certain behaviour but calling the convenience initialiser. See `SCNGeometry`: you can add `SCNGeometryElement`s only using the convenience initialiser, therefore one can't inherit from it.

Comment: This is a very poor language design decision. From the very beginning of my new app I decided to develop with swift I need to call NSWindowController.init(windowNibName) from my subclass, and I just cannot do that :(

Comment: What if the superclass has no designated initializers?

Comment: @9000 In what situation would a class have no designated initializers? Give it a try in a playground.

Comment: @CraigOtis Suppose you make `MyViewController` that subclasses  `UIViewController`, and you don't write any initializers in it, then you make `TestViewController` that subclasses `MyViewController`. `MyViewController` has no designated initializers, so you can't make any initializers in `TestViewController` that call `super.init()`. I ran into this kind of problem and had to work around it by making `MyViewController` have some bogus initializer that calls `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)`, then I called that in `TestViewController`.

Comment: @sudo If you don't declare any initializers in a subclass, that subclass will automatically inherit all the initializers of its superclass. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID222

Comment: @AndyHin Yes, but the problem is the inherited initializers are not "designated" initializers, so subclasses of the subclass can't call them in their own initializers. I don't know whether this was fixed in newer versions of Swift; maybe it was because I haven't run into it in a long time.

Comment: @Robert:
Did Apple respond by now?

Comment: @Kaiserludi: Nothing useful, it was closed with the following response: "This is by design and any relevant  bugs have been sorted out in this area."

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP’s question. Should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Apple has shot itself in the foot open sourcing the swift spec. Hence do not expect a meaningful answer from them. This is spinning out of control the way c++ did with the feature bloat and "unfortunate" design decisions.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Robert Ah.  It seems like the "why" turns out to be "because convenience initializers work differently than expected".  Specifically, according to beba's answer, convenience initializers don't call their own class's designated init, they call the _runtime_ class's designated init.  Normally, I guess this means the convenience inits stick around through subclasses, arguably making them more convenient, but in the desired case, calling a convenience init from the designated init would result in the c-init calling right back to the d-init you started with, eventually yielding stack overflow.

Answer (score 27):

Consider

```
class A
{
    var a: Int
    var b: Int

    init (a: Int, b: Int) {
        print("Entering A.init(a,b)")
        self.a = a; self.b = b
    }

    convenience init(a: Int) {
        print("Entering A.init(a)")
        self.init(a: a, b: 0)
    }

    convenience init() {
        print("Entering A.init()")
        self.init(a:0)
    }
}


class B : A
{
    var c: Int

    override init(a: Int, b: Int)
    {
        print("Entering B.init(a,b)")
        self.c = 0; super.init(a: a, b: b)
    }
}

var b = B()
```

Because all designated initializers of class A are overridden, class B will inherit all convenience initializers of A. So executing this will output

```
Entering A.init()
Entering A.init(a:)
Entering B.init(a:,b:)
Entering A.init(a:,b:)
```

Now, if the designated initializer B.init(a:b:) would be allowed to call the base class convenience initializer A.init(a:), this would result in a recursive call to B.init(a:,b:).

Comment: That's easy to work around. As soon as you call a superclass' convenience initializer from within a designated initializer, the superclass' convenience initializers would no longer be inherited.

Comment: @fluidsonic but that would be insane because your structure and class methods would be changing depending on how they were used. Imagine the debugging fun!

Comment: @kdazzle Neither the class's structure nor its class methods would change. Why should they? -- The only problem I can think of is that convenience initializers must dynamically delegate to a subclass's designated initializer when inherited and statically to it's own class's designated initializer when not inherited but delegated to from a subclass.

Comment: I think you can also get a similar recursion problem with normal methods. That depends on your decision when calling methods. For example, it would be silly if a language didn't allow recursive calls because you could get into an infinite loop. Programmers should understand what they are doing. :)

Comment: Interestingly, this isn't just an explanation of the safeguards convenience vs. designated initializers provide, it's a solution for compile errors like `Convenience initializer for 'MySubclass' must delegate (with 'self.init') rather than chaining to a superclass initializer (with 'super.init')`— the solution being to just override all of the superclass's designated initializers with basic implementations that pass everything to the corresponding `super.init(…)`.  A small edit to the answer making that point clearer would be .

Answer (score 17):

It's because you can end up with an infinite recursion. Consider:

```
class SuperClass {
    init() {
    }

    convenience init(value: Int) {
        // calls init() of the current class
        // so init() for SubClass if the instance
        // is a SubClass
        self.init()
    }
}

class SubClass : SuperClass {
    override init() {
        super.init(value: 10)
    }
}
```

and look at:

```
let a = SubClass()
```

which will call `SubClass.init()` which will call `SuperClass.init(value:)` which will call `SubClass.init()`.

The designated/convenience init rules are designed that a class initialisation will always be correct.

Comment: While a subclass may not explicitly call convenience initializers from its superclass, it may _inherit_ them, given that the subclass supplies implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers (se [e.g. this example](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/26c7e54c3465861a632330f9eaf673dd)). Hence your example above is indeed true, but is a special case not explicitly related to a superclass's convenience initializer, but rather to the fact that a designated initializer _may not call a convenience one_, since this will yield to recursive scenarios such as the one above.

Answer (score 2):

Consider extracting the initialization code from your convenient `init()` to a new helper function `foo()`, call `foo(...)` to do the initialization in your sub-class.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around for this. It's not super pretty, but it solves the problem of not knowing a superclass's values or wanting to set default values. 
All you have to do is create an instance of the superclass, using the convenience `init`, right in the `init` of the subclass. Then you call the designated `init` of the super using the instance you just created.

```
class A {
    var x: Int

    init(x: Int) {
        self.x = x
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(x: 0)
    }
}

class B: A {
    init() {
        // calls A's convenience init, gets instance of A with default x value
        let intermediate = A() 

        super.init(x: intermediate.x) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the WWDC-video "403 intermediate Swift" at 18:30 for an in depth explanation of initializers and their inheritance. As I understood it, consider the following:

```
class Dragon {
    var legs: Int
    var isFlying: Bool

    init(legs: Int, isFlying: Bool) {
        self.legs = legs
        self.isFlying = isFlying
    }

    convenience initWyvern() { 
        self.init(legs: 2, isFlying: true)
    }
}
```

But now consider a Wyrm-subclass: 
A Wyrm is a Dragon with no legs and no wings. So the Initializer for a Wyvern (2 legs, 2 wings) is wrong for it! That error can be avoided if the convenience Wyvern-Initializer simply can't be called but only the full designated Initializer:

```
class Wyrm: Dragon {
    init() {
        super.init(legs: 0, isFlying: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not really a reason. What if I make a subclass when `initWyvern` makes sense to be called?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not convinced. There's nothing stopping `Wyrm` from overriding the number of legs after it calls a convenience initializer.

Comment: It is the reason given in the WWDC video (only with cars -> racecars and a boolean hasTurbo-property). If the subclass implements all designated initializers, than it too inherits the convenience initializers. I kinda see the sense in it, also I honestly had no much trouble with the way Objective-C worked. See also the new convention to call super.init last in the init, not first like in Objective-C.

Comment: IMO the convention to call super.init "last" is not conceptually new, it is the same as that in objective-c, just that there, everything was being assigned a initial value(nil, 0, whatever) automatically. Its just that in Swift, we have to do this phase os initialisation ourselves. A benefit to this approach is we also have an option to assign a different initial value.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just have two initializers - one with a default value?

```
class A {
  var x: Int

  init(x: Int) {
    self.x = x
  }

  init() {
    self.x = 0
  }
}

class B: A {
  override init() {
    super.init()

    // Do something else
  }
}

let s = B()
s.x // 0
```