# NSWindow initialiser with screen parameter causes Fatal Error upon initialisation

Tags: swift, cocoa, nswindow

I have a simple subclass of NSWindow, and have some logic that returns an NSWindow.
When passing in `screen` into the initialiser of `NSWindow`, the app causes a

```
Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(contentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:)' for class 'myClass'
```

Here's a chunk of code:

```swift
class myClass: NSWindow {
    init() {
        ...

        super.init(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100),
                   styleMask: .borderless,
                   backing: .buffered,
                   defer: false,
                   screen: /* returned NSScreen */) // this crashes

        ...
   }
}
```

I'm not sure what's causing this, I've checked that `NSScreens.screens` returns an array of two non-nil screens (for my two monitors), and I can fetch all necessary data from them.

Why does passing it into the initialiser crash?

(I've made sure the logic is not the issue here; testing with just `NSScreen.screens[0]` in the `screen:`  parameter causes this to crash too.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: @Willeke This code is very much reproducible, it's as simple as it gets. Pass `NSScreen.screens[0]` into the `screen: ` parameter and you get a reproducible example. Thank you.

Comment: I tried your code and got "Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'NSWindow'" instead of "Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(contentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:)' for class 'myClass'". The code doesn't compile. Creating a minimal reproducable example will help you find the cause of the issue.

Comment: Yeah, ended up getting the same thing – please see my updated answer. Thanks nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Xcode was being horrible with error messages as usual. Ran this in a brand new test project and got the actual error of

```
Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'NSWindow'
```

The initialiser in `NSWindow` with screen is its convenience initialiser, and can't be called from a subclass.
Read here for more: [Why can't Swift initializers call convenience initializers on their superclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24122421/17569741)

Initialising an `NSWindow` itself without subclassing may be a temporary solution depending on your app structure.